# Multi substitution on python list

Tags: python, list, replace

I'm working on a project that deciphers the secret sentence.

when I input
apple.appleapple.pear.orange.lemon

I want it to change into
A.B.E.R.T

I used split and replace to do it. However, I can't find a way to change
"apple" into A and
"appleapple" into B
at the same time because when I use replace(), appleapple changes into AA
This is what I've tried.

```
list1 = n.split()
list2 = f's.split([\\.]) : {list1}'

print(list2.replace("apple", "A"))
print(list2.replace("appleapple", "B"))
print(list2)
```

Comment: You could change it to replace `appleapple` first, then `apple` second.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case you should make use of dictionaries instead of replacing all the time. You will be thankful to do so if the 'vocabulary' of your project increases. I would do this:

```
dictionary = {
    'apple': 'A',
    'appleapple': 'B',
    'pear': 'E',
    'orange': 'R',
    'lemon': 'T'
}

original = 'apple.appleapple.pear.orange.lemon'
words_list = original.split('.')

result = [dictionary.get(word, 'unknown') for word in words_list]
result = '.'.join(result)

print(result)
```

The above would print this:

```
A.B.E.R.T
```

Note the use of the dictionary's `get()` method to add a default value if the read word is not found in your vocabulary. For example, with the same dictionary and the string `apple.appleapple.pear.orange.lemon.otherthing` (I added 'otherthing' at the end) we would have as result the string `A.B.E.R.T.unknown`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary instead

```
secret_dict = {'apple':'A','appleapple':'B','pear':'E','orange':'R','lemon':'T'}
n = 'apple.appleapple.pear.orange.lemon'
words_in_n=n.split('.')
resulting_secret_words = [secret_dict.get(word) for word in resulting_secret_words]
secret_sentence = ''.join(resulting_secret_words)
print(secret_sentence)
```